# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath when using jersey API and deploying on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jersey, openshift

I have used Jersey for Rest Services.I have added the jersey-core,jersey-server jars in WEB-INF/lib folder but tomcat does not deploy the WAR and specifies the following exception:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey uses the concept of various containers to adapt to the surrounding environment. This way it can run in a pure http container, such as grizzly, or - as in your case - in the servlet container.

In order to make Jersey work, you need to add the `jersey-servlet` dependency as well:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But the `ClassNotFoundException` itself is caused by missing JAX-RS API jar on your classpath:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You seem to be managing the dependencies manually, which can become rather challenging pretty fast. If you don't want to (or cannot) consider using some tool to do this for you (gradle, maven), I'd suggest to at least take the `pom.xml` files from relevant jersey modules to explore the dependencies of the module to make sure not to forget some of the prerequisites.

All the source codes are available on github, e.g. see the [containers pom](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/pom.xml#L83-L86).

Hope this helps,
Adam

Comment: The link to the `pom.xml` is unfortunately not valid anymore. The repo has been archived.

Comment: Hi, I see. If the question is still relevant for anybody, the repository can be found under [eclipse-ee4j](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey) now. The structure is still similar after years, so the originally linked pom.xml is [this one](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/2.x/pom.xml).